# Decomposition of time series vs ARIMA model

Tags: time-series, arima

I am new to time series analysis, and I amm trying to understand the concepts behind this  analysis.
But I am still confused about the methods used to do such analyss, and what is the difference between the decomposition of time series or using an ARIMA model.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Time series decomposition generally involves partitioning a signal into *seasonal*, *trend*, *residual* and sometimes *level*, *holiday* etc. components, which assumes additive or multiplicative relationships. [`seasonal_decompose`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose.html#statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose) method in `statsmodel.tsa` library is a simple application of this. A more advanced version, which applies [Box-Cox](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Power_transform) transformation beforehand automatically and accepts multiple seasonality frequencies, is [`mstl`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.5/topics/mstl) in R. Facebook's [Prophet](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/) also employs seasonal decomposition in itself. And, usually, a ARMA model on residuals followed by a decomposition step is a typical approach in analysis.

In ARIMA, there isn't a decomposition of such type. It's a generalization of ARMA models, in which we first difference the series and fit an ARMA model. The differencing step is applied to make the signal *more* stationary, by eliminating trend and seasonality components. ARIMA models considering seasonality are called SARIMA, but it also doesn't involve decomposition.

Comment: The assumption that decompostion be done first is due to the fact that Prophet lacks full capability to consider the general problem as the up-front filtering can inject structure ala the Slutsky Effect.  http://www.jstor.org/stable/1907241